# How can i configure parcel bundler to use npm packages in the browser environment?

Tags: axios, parcel

I'm trying to use **axios** package, to send http request to the Express server using **parcel 2.9.3 bundler installed grobally** , 
 But if i try to import axios  in one of the my  module i see an error in browser terminal saying '**Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "axios". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".**'.

The details of my files is as follow 
**1. package.json**

```
{
  "name": "Natours",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Learning node, express and mongoDB",
  "source": "./public/js/index.js",
  "module": "./public/js/bundle.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js",
    "start:prod": "SET NODE_ENV=production&nodemon server.js",
    "watch:js": "parcel watch",
    "build:js": "parcel watch ./public/js/index.js --dist-dir ./public/js"
  },
  "targets": {
    "main": {
      "includeNodeModules": true,
      "context": "browser"
    }
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "axios": "^1.5.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-mongo-sanitize": "^2.2.0",
    "express-rate-limit": "^6.9.0",
    "helmet": "^7.0.0",
    "hpp": "^0.2.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.1",
    "mongoose": "^7.4.3",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.4",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "slugify": "^1.6.6",
    "validator": "^13.11.0",
    "xss-clean": "^0.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0"
  }
}
```

**2. Entry file(index.js)**

```
import { msg } from './login.js';
 console.log('From client side');
 console.log(msg);
```

**3. login.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';
 console.log(axios);
 export const msg = 'Hellow from  the login file';
```

**4. base.pug**

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
    head
      block head
        meta(charset="UTF-8")
        meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible", content="IE=edge")
        meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/style.css")
        link(rel="shortcut icon", href="/img/favicon.png", type="image/png")
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,700")
        script(defer type="module" src="/js/bundle.js") 
        title Natours | #{title}
    body
      // HEADER
      include _header

    // CONTENT
    block content
      h1 This is a placeholder heading
    // FOOTER
    include _footer
```

**I have tried by doing the following**

**1.** Setting include node modules to true and setting context to browser in target option in package.json, still it did not work.

```
"targets": {
    "main": {
      "includeNodeModules": true,
       "context": "browser"
    }
```

**2.** Using "module"  or  "main"  ,still it did not work

```
"module": "./public/js/bundle.js"
```

```
"main": "./public/js/bundle.js"
```

**Any one who have idea about this issue please help me.**